# Regular Expression to match MM/YYYY or m/YYYYY

Tags: regex, date, regex-lookarounds

I would like to see a regular expression that matches the following date formats.

```
1/2017
01/2017
12/2017
```

Here is what I have so far, however it only matches the last two. What am I missing?

```
((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})
```

I also don't want it to match at all if the format is 12/1/2017 (MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy)

Thanks,

Comment: Try `^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `0` optional by adding `?` next to the `0` in your regex.

`((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gki3su/1)

**EDIT:** Surround the above regex with `\b` (border) so it does **not** match `5/21/2017` at all.

`\b((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})\b`

[Updated Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gki3su/2)

**EDIT 2:** Updated regex as per Glenn's comment:

```
(?:^|[^\/\d])\K(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}\b
```

[Updated Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gki3su/8)

Comment: This worked once I took @ganesshkumar's ^$ suggestion

Comment: You'll get a false match if the format is mm/dd/YYYY and the day looks like a month (e.g. 11). `\b` is insufficient since it will match between a `/` (non-word char) and a digit (word char). I'd suggest `(^|[^/\d])\K((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})\b`

Comment: better: `(?:^|[^\/\d])\K(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}\b`

Comment: @glennjackman Your regex looks good, except a minor thing - the missing escape for the first `/`

Comment: fixed in 2nd comment

Answer (score 3):

`((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})`. The first input doesn't have 0. Adding + will match zero or one occurrence of `0`

Comment: This matches the second half of 1/2017 in the string 5/21/2017.

Comment: Add `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end of the regular expression, to match the entire input and not a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
/^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4})$/gm
```

Will match:

```
1/2017
01/2017
12/2017
```

But will not match:

```
12/1/2017
13/2017
111/2017
/2017
```

The modifier `g` is for global.

The modifier `m` is for multi-line, which makes possible the use of ^ and $ to delimiter an start and end.

https://regex101.com/r/ompmyK/3